# Read in a list of random names, past tense verbs and fruits and randomly create sentences

Tags: python

This python program is requiring me to read in a list of random names fruits and verbs and then sort them into a list and print out random sentences that make sense. I am struggling how to produce the random sentences. I have the lists sorted, but it states 'pick' is not defined.

here is my function:

```
def getData():
    list = []
    name_list = []
    fruit_list = []
    verb_list = [] 

name_input = input()
fruit_input = input()
verb_input = input()

seperator = ','

namestr = name_input.split(seperator)
fruitstr = fruit_input.split(seperator)
verbstr = verb_input.split(seperator)

name_list.append(namestr)
fruit_list.append(fruitstr)
verb_list.append(verbstr)

list = name_list + fruit_list + verb_list

return list
```

here is the main function that creates the sentence(given in the problem):

```
def main():
    seed = int(input())
    print("The seed is", seed)
    names,verbs,fruit = getData()
    print("NAMES:", names)
    print("VERBS:", verbs)
    print("FRUIT:", fruit)
    random.seed(seed)
    for i in range(10):
        n = pick(names, random.randint(1,1000))
        v = pick(verbs, random.randint(1,1000))
        f = pick(fruit, random.randint(1,1000))
    print(n,v,"the",f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:

```
The seed is 42
 NAMES: ['Adam', 'Betty', 'Charlie', 'Debbie', 'Elaine', 'Frank' 'George', 'Harry', 'Igor', 'Jack', 'Kevin', 'Larry', 'Moe', 'Nancy', 'Ophelia', 'Phil', 'Quentin']

VERBS: ['had', 'found', 'got', 'made', 'knew', 'took', 'saw', 'wanted', 'used', 'found', 'tried']

FRUIT: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry', 'fig', 'grape']

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 59, in <module>
        main()
    File "main.py", line 51, in main
        n = pick(names, random.randint(1,1000))
    NameError: name 'pick' is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: As it says, pick is not defined. There is no such function as pick. If you want to pick a random element from a list, check out `random.shuffle`

Comment: check out [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: @bosnjak `random.shuffle` is not what he wants. `random.shuffle` shuffles the list in place

Comment: Is knowing the random seed and reproducing the same results important for your implementation?

Comment: Also, I assume you want to move that print statement _inside_ the for loop and actually print 10 sentences, right?

Comment: So really, it has more to do with writing `pick` and `getData` functions that take certain inputs, correct? Using `random.choice` in that case, would not be the correct approach. If you cannot modify `main`, you have no choice but to write your code so that it fits. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to modify the `main` function, then there are a couple points you can learn by looking at the code in `main`:

**FIRST** The line `names,verbs,fruit = getData()` tells you that `getData()` is really returning 3 separate lists, and they are being assigned via python magic to the `names`, `verbs`, and `fruit` variables. So your `getData()` function needs to return the three lists in a tuple like this: `return (name_list, verb_list, fruit_list)` **in that order**.

**SECOND** As you discovered from the error message, the function `pick` does not exist, so the line(s) `pick(fruit, random.randint(1,1000))` should tell you that you need to *write* a function called `pick` that will return an item from a given list based on the integer passed into it. Perhaps you have extra instruction as to what to do with this integer, but I would assume you could use modular arithmetic to retrieve the item at that index, like so:

```
def pick (items, i):
    return items[i % len(items)]
```

**LASTLY** you can shorten the ingesting of the input to a single line each (if you don't have to account for error handling). So all together, your `getData` function could end up looking something like this:

```
def getData():
    separator = ','
    name_list = input().split(separator)
    verb_list = input().split(separator)
    fruit_list = input().split(separator)
    return (name_list, verb_list, fruit_list)
```

Comment: Doesn't that modify the 'Main' part of the production (the function provided) in which they do not want you to change? Or should the random.choice be used in the function that I created getData()? It says that pick isn't defined and I must use pick because it says that I cant edit the function, should I still go about doing this? Im confused as to where to place this.

Comment: Addtion: Does the 'seed' variable have to do with any of this?

Comment: Oh, are you not allowed to modify the contents of the main function? In that case, you need to write a function called `pick`. That `pick` function can implement `random.choice`

Comment: Yes that makes much more sense.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a Idea.

```
import random
NAMES = ['Adam', 'Betty', 'Charlie', 'Debbie', 'Elaine', 'Frank' 'George','Harry', 'Igor', 'Jack', 'Kevin', 'Larry', 'Moe', 'Nancy', 'Ophelia', 'Phil', 'Quentin']
VERBS = ['had', 'found', 'got', 'made', 'knew', 'took', 'saw', 'wanted', 'used', 'found', 'tried']
FRUIT = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry', 'fig', 'grape']

sCounter = 0
fCounter = 5



while sCounter <= fCounter:
    sCounter += 1 
    print("{0} {1} the {2}").format(random.choice(NAMES),random.choice(VERBS),random.choice(FRUIT))
```

Output:

```
Quentin found the fig
Betty found the date
Kevin used the cherry
Nancy got the grape
Larry used the cherry
Jack wanted the cherry
```